# DDD: Can anyone explain the diffrences between DTO, Aggregate Root and Detached Entity?

Tags: java, jpa, domain-driven-design, microservices

I'm a bit puzzled in figuring out the differences between these three. Presumed I have a Customer -> Address relation the (JPA) Detached Entity will have this as well (Eager Loading presumed). Where is the need to have an additional Aggregate Root? Where is the need to have a DTO? Is it all more or less the same?

One of the reasons might be that the JPA compliant Entity has some info the client is simply not interested in, e.g. `@Entity`, `@Id`, `@OneToMany`.

I can convert it easily to JSON/XML using JAX-RS/-WS and almost every client can deal with it, so where is the need for having it? Is it all almost the same or do I miss something important?

Comment: AggregateRoot does not belong to DDD? Hmmm ... I did not expect me being so wrong. Unfortunately Martin Fowler was mislead as well: http://martinfowler.com/bliki/DDD_Aggregate.html. Anyhow ... I'm interested to know whether my service interface ... the one which belongs to a Microservice ... should return a Detached Entity or should I transfer it into graph of related TOs ... and what is the diference, where are the benefits ... Just one hint my friend: before downvoting try to clarify, ok?

Comment: Ah, I was thinking about query roots. Looks like I am doubly unqualified to answer your question :)  sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: No problem and thx for the effort ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You will create *aggregate root* if you follow DDD principles wether you're using JPA or not.  This is one of the very fundamental building blocks in DDD.  From the book Eric Evan's DDD book:

> Aggregates mark off the scope within which invariants have to be
>   maintaned at every stage of lifecycle.  The following patterns,
>   factories and repositories, operate on aggregates.

DTO and detached entity are related to JPA (technical constraints).  An *aggregate root* is also an *entity*.  When the *aggregate root* become unmanaged (by persistence context), it is called *detached entity*.

Perhaps your question can be rephrased into: should I return *aggregate root* as *detached entity* or DTO?  The answer is subjective and depends on your environment.

The benefit of returning *aggregate root* as *detached entity* is you don't need to create a new DTO class.  You can also call methods owned by the *aggregate root*.  The disadvantage is you usually won't populate the complete object graph for performance reason because some *aggregate roots* can have a very deep hierarchy.  This will lead to lazy loading exception if not handled properly.

Returning DTO instead of *aggregate root* is considered as more robust design.  You will need to create a new DTO class for every *'use case'* of the *aggregate root*.  This maybe too cumbersome for small system, but if you're using DDD, I believe your requirement is complex.

Comment: Thx for the clarification ... was definitely helpful. I was thinking more or less the same way but now I got the idea of being in sync with my thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Humm, I don't really understand what is your real need ? What is the problem that you try to solve with trying to use DDD concepts or DTO...

DTO is not comparable to aggregate root (an entity as well), an entity has datas and behaviors (that is not the case for DTO, that is simply data).

So, the domain model, should be domain Driven ;-), and some building blocks are usefull to implement it, ex: Entity, Aggregate... And when you use an ORM, it can be hard to isolate your domain, so you have to try to have something pure in your Domain with less noise as you can. There are many strategies to solve it.

You can find more there : http://elegantcode.com/2009/11/13/dtos-ddd-the-anemic-domain-model/

Comment: The actual problem is to describe a new architecture for an existing software (which needs to be thrown away due to missing concepts in the architecture). Thanks for the link!